# PDF annotations: How to know if "a box is empty"?

Tags: xetex, pdf, boxes, dvipdfmx

Extract from `dvipdfmx` documentation:

> Warning: No annotation will be constructed if the content between `pdf:bann` and `pdf:eann` is an empty box.

My MWE (via xelatex):

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
http://www.tug.org%
\special{pdf:eann}

\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
\phantom{http://www.tug.org}%
\special{pdf:eann}

\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\special{pdf:eann}

\end{document}
```

The second and third annotations do not work!

How to make a non-empy box with invisible content?

Subsidiary question: why this limitation?

Comment: With a "not really" empty box it works; for instance the `TS1` encoding (`\usepackage{textcomp}`) has a `\textcapitalcompwordmark` invisible character and you can put it at the start and end of a box with the right dimensions. When `fontenc` is loaded, use some invisible character, such as `U+00A0`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems that annotations require at least a real character, so `\phantom` or `\rule` don't do any good.

If you're using "standard" fonts, then you can use the `textcomp` package that sports a `\textcapitalcompwordmark` character which is invisible and as high as the capital letters. So

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\newcommand{\myinvchar}{\textcapitalcompwordmark}

\newcommand{\emptybox}[1]{%
  \sbox0{#1}\makebox[\wd0][s]{\myinvchar\hss\myinvchar}%
}

\begin{document}

X\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
http://www.tug.org%
\special{pdf:eann}X

X\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
\emptybox{http://www.tug.org}%
\special{pdf:eann}X

\end{document}
```

will produce a "clickable space":

[image]

If you're using OpenType fonts via `fontspec`, an invisible character might be U+00A0:

```
\newcommand{\myinvchar}{\char\string"00A0 }
```

Comment: Thanks for these solutions. I need this to complete my ocgx package. Is `textcomp` solution (`\textcapitalcompwordmark`)  usable in any case? (What do you mean by "standard" fonts?)

Comment: It seems so. You might want to do also `\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont` in the box, in order to avoid spurious messages and do some tricks for adjusting the height.

Comment: If I add `\usepackage{fontspec}` in your code, the height of annotation change. Why?

Comment: @PaulGaborit That's a good question. Also for the "non empty" box.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you need a character there. If you are using a Unicode font you can use U200B which is a zero width space:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\font\zzz="[lmroman10-regular]" at 10pt

\begin{document}
\zzz

\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
http://www.tug.org%
\special{pdf:eann}


a


\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
\mbox{\strut ^^^^200b\phantom{http://www.tug.org}^^^^200b}%
\special{pdf:eann}



b


\special{pdf:bann << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
 ^^^^200b\rule{1cm}{1cm} ^^^^200b
\special{pdf:eann}

\end{document}
```

Comment: why is the second box wider? (you said `^^^^200b` took up no space).

Comment: @jfbu Because I left a space after the rule before the ^^^^200b. I must have done that on purpose, surely I wouldn't have left in white space by mistake:-)

Comment: ok, but I was referring to the `phantom` one... I must be missing something _obvious_!

Comment: @jfbu oh I see, no idea:-)

Answer (score 7):

From [this tugboat article](http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/tb30-1/tb94cho.pdf) you can use `pdf:ann` if you want a box taking up no space. I know nothing to all this but just tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

A\special{pdf:ann bbox 0 0 12 12 << /Subtype /Link
  /BS << /Type /Border /W 0.5 /S /S >>
  /A << /S /URI
    /URI (http://www.tug.org) >> >>}%
B

\end{document}
```

And indeed the output contains a clickable box taking up no space (`B` follows `A` immediately). (it is as if the clickable area had been done with an `rlap`).

Comment: You can add `\hspace*{12bp}` in front of `B`. Or enclose the `\special` in `\makebox[12bp][l]{...}`